# Как обратиться к элементу JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элементы class1. Каждый из них содержит один дочерний элемент с class2.

```
$(".class1").bind("click", function () {
     $(".class2").css("display","inline");
});
```

При нажатии на элемент с классом class1 все элементы с class2 получат css свойство. Как применить свойство только к ребёнку нажатого элемента? Известно лишь имя класса. Элементы приходят с сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".class1").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).find(".class2").css("display","inline");
});
```